# Error MySQL CentOS - Starting MySQLCouldn't find MySQL server

Tags: linux, centos, mysql

I can not make any operation in mysql:

```
root@server2 [/]# /etc/init.d/mysql status
MySQL is not running, but lock file (/var/lock/subsys/mysql[FAILED]
root@server2 [/]# /etc/init.d/mysql start
Starting MySQL.The server quit without updating PID file (/[FAILED]mysql/server2.myaddress.com.br.pid).
root@server2 [/]# /etc/init.d/mysql stop
MySQL server PID file could not be found!                  [FAILED]
root@server2 [/]# /etc/init.d/mysql restart
MySQL server PID file could not be found!                  [FAILED]
Starting MySQL.The server quit without updating PID file (/[FAILED]mysql/server2.myaddress.com.br.pid).
root@server2 [/]# mysql -u root
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

My file /etc/my.cnf:

```
root@server2 [~]# cat /etc/my.cnf
[mysqld]
user = mysql
skip-external-locking
key_buffer = 384M
max_allowed_packet=268435456
max_connections = 500
max_user_connections = 35
wait_timeout=40
connect_timeout=10
table_cache = 512
sort_buffer_size = 2M
read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
thread_cache_size = 8
query_cache_size = 32M
thread_concurrency = 8
server-id       = 1
skip-innodb

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 256M
sort_buffer_size = 256M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

Searching in some posts, I found that some program may be holding mysql. Follow the command checked:

```
root@server2 [~]# lsof | grep mysql
tailwatch 20718      root  mem       REG        3,5    206553    8922204 /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/perl/514/lib/perl5/cpanel_lib/i386-linux-64int/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so
```

yum info mysql-server

```
root@server2 [~]# yum info mysql-server
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.aol.com
 * extras: centos.chi.host-engine.com
 * updates: mirror.lug.udel.edu
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Error: No matching Packages to list
```

Other information ..

- There is no process running mysql.
- CentOS release 5.10 (Final)
- I already deleted files with extension .err and tried again. But it did not work.
- When I try to start mysql in safe mode, apparently there is no error. But still does not work and any subsequent operation does not work.
- I've tried also move ib_logfile logs to mysql create new files. Unsuccessful attempt.

Log in /var/lib/mysql/server2.myaddress.com.br.err

```
140829 14:23:58 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140829 14:23:58 [Note] Plugin 'InnoDB' is disabled.
/usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13)
140829 14:23:58 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
140829 14:23:58 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
140829 14:23:58 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
140829 14:23:58 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
140829 14:23:58 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/proxies_priv.frm' (errno: 13)
140829 14:23:58 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Can't find file: './mysql/proxies_priv.frm' (errno: 13)
140829 14:23:58 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/server2.myaddress.com.br.pid ended
```

Comment: Erm /usr/local/mysql appears to be required but is missing ?

Comment: Dont exists that path in server. I remove this line in my.cnf and get this error: Starting MySQL..The server quit without updating PID file ([FAILED]/mysql/server2.myaddress.com.br.pid).

Comment: I updated the post with the commands without the line /usr/local/mysql in my.cnf. It was a mistake.

Comment: Are there any relevant messages in your logs ?

Comment: There is not the folder: /var/log/mysql

Comment: I updated the post with the log in /var/lib/mysql/server2.myaddress.com.br.err

Comment: I've tried also move ib_logfile logs to mysql create new files. Unsuccessful attempt.

Comment: Can someone explain to me why the negative votes?

Comment: The downvotes are probably because it appears you have put very little effort into solving the problem yourself, likely due to not having much knowledge about the subject.  This is a site for professionals, as a professional you should at least be able to figure out where your log files are and work from there.  Have you even bothered to check if the files that your log says mysqld cannot find actually exist?  We shouldn't have to probe you for basic troubleshooting information like this.

Comment: Soon after my comment about the nonexistence of the logs folder, I updated the post with information from the logs. Anyway, I'm actually not in reason. I am a web programmer and I am trying to troubleshoot a network. Many professionals would choose to reinstall mysql. But I'm trying to solve and understand the problem. I will continue to seek a solution. Appreciate any future help 'even when I wrong'.

Comment: About logs I found, I tried in various forums with similar questions about existing problems. But no attempt worked.

Comment: You *still* haven't stated whether the files that your log file says it cannot find actually exist or not.  You're never going to solve the problem if you ignore the errors the application is explicitly giving you.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a new mysql server or an existing one? It appears to be missing it's data folder. There is also no data folder defined in the configuration, so it'll use the default.

If you have not yet created a MySQL data directory, you need to create it with the command:

```
mysql_install_db
```

Comment: I already tried it. But not works..

Comment: Whats the output/error you get?

Comment: I had to 'rm -rf' the datadir a few times.  Ultimately it worked when deleted the datadir, ran 
# yum reinstall mysql-community-server.x86_64
# mysql_install_db --user=mysql
Also might be worthwhile to note that at some point I changed the owner of datadir (chown -R mysql:mysql <data_dir>), but that's because I originally ran mysql_install_db as 'root'.

Answer (score 1):

`errno: 13` is permission denied, which means the database files exist, but MySQL doesn't have permission to access them. To resolve the problem, fix the permissions and SELinux contexts.